# Insert normalizeOption in tflite model with command line

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to insert my custom model into [android tensorflow lite object detection](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android). I created a MobileNetv2 model using tflite_convert and inserted it into the Android demo project, but an error asking me to specify the NormalizationOptions metadata occurred.

```
    Process: org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection, PID: 6420
    java.lang.AssertionError: Error occurred when initializing ObjectDetector: Input tensor has type kTfLiteFloat32: it requires specifying NormalizationOptions metadata to preprocess input images.
```

The above phenomenon occurs even though mean_value and std_dev_values ​​are specified as shown in the code below. Is there a way to enter NormalizationOption on the command line?

```
!tflite_convert \
  --input_shape=1,300,300,3 \
  --input_arrays=normalized_input_image_tensor \
  --output_arrays=TFLite_Detection_PostProcess,TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1,TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2,TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3 \
  --allow_custom_ops \
  --graph_def_file=/content/models/research/fine_tuned_model/tflite/tflite_graph.pb \
  --output_file="/content/models/research/fine_tuned_model/final_model.tflite" \
  --inference_type=FLOAT \
  --mean_values=128 \
  --std_dev_values=128 \
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [official object detection example](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples/object_detection/overview#android) two variants: 1) using task library, 2) using interpreter API directly. The default build variant uses the task library, and it expects the object detection model to have [metadata added](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/metadata#adding_metadata).

Looks like the `NormalizationOption` is from the metadata section, so please try adding metadata following the guide linked above, or use a different build variant of the example app to not use the task library.

Comment: Thank you! even after 11 years this helped me quite a lot.

Comment: what? after 11 years? how come? :D

Comment: Maybe he misread years :)